# Run any function that is stored in an interface{}

Tags: go

I want to store a function with **any parameters** in an `interface{}` and be able to run it elsewhere.

So it could store a `func(string) string` or a `func(int, int) string` or etc, but I need to be able to call it later and be able to tell it what type of function it is. I tried to use `.(func(string) string)` and `.(func(int,int) string)`, but got nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought through how you world expect a function signature cast like that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the reflect package?

Particularly [Type](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) and [ValueOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) and [Value.Call](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call).

Comment: I did, but never call the Call function. Worked perfectly, thanks!